# ProgressDialog doesnt work perfectly

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Hello i am getting zip file from server and i have written code for it.

I am showing progressdialog also

Here is code

```
public class DownloadImageFromUrl : AsyncTask<string, string, string>
{
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private Context context;

    public DownloadImageFromUrl(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnPreExecute()
    {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);

        pd.SetMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");

        pd.Indeterminate = false;

        pd.Max = 100;

        pd.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Horizontal);

        pd.SetCancelable(true);

        pd.Show();

        base.OnPreExecute();

    }

    protected override void OnProgressUpdate(params string[] values)
    {
        base.OnProgressUpdate(values);

        pd.SetProgressNumberFormat(values[0]);
        Log.Verbose("values", "" + values[0]);
        pd.Progress = int.Parse(values[0]);

    }

    protected override void OnPostExecute(string result)
    {
        pd.Dismiss();
    }

    protected override string RunInBackground(params string[] @params)
    {

        var storagePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(storagePath.AbsolutePath, "testfile.zip");
        int count;

        try
        {                    
            URL url = new URL("http://shadikidukan.co.in/abhi/AAA.zip");
            filename = Path.GetFileName(new Uri(url.ToString()).AbsolutePath);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Abhijir" + filename);
            URLConnection connection = url.OpenConnection();

            connection.Connect();

            int LengthOfFile = connection.ContentLength;//Here connection.ContentLength return -1
            Log.Verbose("length", ""+LengthOfFile);
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.OpenStream(), 8192);

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.Read(data)) != -1)

                {

                    total += count;
                    PublishProgress("" + (int)((total / 100) / LengthOfFile));
                    output.Write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.Flush();

                output.Close();

                input.Close();

            }



            catch (Exception e)

            {

                System.Console.WriteLine("Abhijir"+e.Message);
            }
            return null;

        }

    }
```

connection.ContentLength return -1

and when file is downloading it display negative values and progress is not incrementing..

in progressupdate method it always get negative values

```
protected override void OnProgressUpdate(params string[] values)
{
    base.OnProgressUpdate(values);

    pd.SetProgressNumberFormat(values[0]);
    Log.Verbose("values", "" + values[0]);//values[0] has negative values
    pd.Progress = int.Parse(values[0]);

}
```

how to overcome that problem and display proper value in progressdialog.

Answer (score 1):

A content-length of -1 indicates that the header is missing or should be ignored. This usually means that the server is using [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). Per design, you cannot know the total length of the file you're trying to download, and therefore can't display a progress indicator.

Try to download the file in a desktop browser, you'll see that the total length isn't displayed until the transfer has ended.

Comment: What is the solution for it sir

Comment: There is no solution. As I said, you cannot get a content-length because of the way the protocol itself is designed. If it's your server, then change the configuration to stop using chunked transfer. If it's not, then you're stuck.

Comment: Ya its my server could you tell me how to change configuration

Comment: I don't know. I have no clue what technology you're using, or how you've set it up. You'll have to search a bit by yourself.